# Mongo: strings converted to date but not 'querable'

Tags: string, mongodb, date

I have a collection with date stored as strings *YYYY-mm-DD_HH:MM:SS.UUUZ* like *2020-10-20_12:15:22.123+0100*

My goal is to query on strings treating those as dates.

What am I doing:
I'm unwinding some header data on multiple documents:

```json
    {
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$events",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
            }
        }
```

and also

```json
    {
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$events.hi2",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
            }
}
```

I'm adding a new field made with the string parsed as Date

```json
    {
            "$addFields": {
                "events.hi2.ConnectTimets": {
                    "$dateFromString": {
                        "dateString": "$events.hi2.ConnectTime",
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%L%Z"
                    }
                }
    }}
```

then on a `$match` stage I try to filter all records with date newer than 1 June 2020:

```json
    {
            "$match":{
                "events.hi2.ConnectTimets": {
                                    "$gt": {"$dateFromString": {
                                                "dateString": "2020-06-01",
                                                "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
                                                 }
                                             }
                                }
                }   
         }
```

my result is `Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms`

even though exists (at least a single document) in the database with a date matching the filter:

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f438dfbf1feb13c4352e9f4"),
        "timestamp" : NumberLong(1598262779045),
        "attribute1" : [ 
            "common"
        ],
        "events" : [ 
            {
                "eventType" : "ty1",
                "timestamp" : NumberLong(1598262779018),
                "docId" : NumberLong(282578800148736),
                "hi2" : {
                    "Priority" : 3,
                    "ClientId" : "client1",
                    "ConnectTime" : "2020-08-24_09:52:58.993+0000",
                    "Direction" : 1
                }
            },
            {
                "eventType" : "ty2",
                "timestamp" : NumberLong(1598262781071),
                "docId" : NumberLong(282578800148736),
                "hi2" : {
                    "ref" : "bbbb"
                    
                }
            }
        ]  
    }
```

When I espected something like

```json
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f438dfbf1feb13c4352e9f4"),
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1598262779045),
            "attribute1" : [ 
                "common"
            ],
            "events" : [ 
                {
                    "eventType" : "ty1",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1598262779018),
                    "docId" : NumberLong(282578800148736),
                    "hi2" : {
                        "Priority" : 3,
                        "ClientId" : "client1",
                        "ConnectTime" : "2020-08-24_09:52:58.993+0000",
                        "Direction" : 1
                 }
    }
    }
```

Note_: the add field is ok because if i fire it without the match stage outputs a field with the string parsed as date

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** store date/time values as string, use always proper `Date` objects.
Then the query is much simpler:

```
db.logging.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         "events.hi2.ConnectTimets": {
            $dateFromString: {
               dateString: "$events.hi2.ConnectTime",
               format: "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%L%Z"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { "events.hi2.ConnectTimets": { $gte: ISODate("2020-06-01") } } }
])
```

When you have to work with date/time values then I recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). Then you query could look like these:

```
{ $match: { "events.hi2.ConnectTimets": { $gte: moment("2020-06-01").toDate() } } }
{ $match: { "events.hi2.ConnectTimets": { $gte: moment("2020-06-01").tz('Europe/Zurich').toDate() } } }
{ $match: { "events.hi2.ConnectTimets": { $lte: moment.tz('Europe/Zurich').endOf('day').toDate() } } }
```